# Declaring union typed variables

Tags: c, unions

I'm exploring some ancient C library and am a bit confused as to why it declares union variables in a certain way and whether or not it makes any difference, example:

```
union banana {
    uint32_t cool[2];
    uint64_t supercool;
};

void main() {
    union banana new_banana; //<- why like this?
    banana other_banana; // <- as opposed to this
}
```

As far as I can tell it doesn't make any difference but you never know.. is there any?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Which one are you asking about? Your question says C but your tag says C++.

Comment: Related http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union

Comment: Well, there's the fact that `banana other_banana;` [isn't actually valid C](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63ce55f187196421). It might be valid C++, but this isn't C++ code.

Comment: to do `banana other_banana` you need to `typedef union { ... } banana;`

Comment: also this is not a question about unions specifically as the same thing happens with structs but i'll let someone else write the answer as i can't right now

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use `typedef` you have to use the `union` in front of banana.

```
typedef union {
    uint32_t cool[2];
    uint64_t supercool;
} banana;
```

Then you can just use `banana`. If you just do as in the example above, then you will have to use `union banana`, and you can even use `banana` for something else. `union banana` and `banana` are different in the example above.

if you try `banana other_banana`as in your example, the compiler should give you `error: unknown type name ‘banana’`